# how can i highlights particular date using datepicker jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How highlight particular date in datepicker.

I have dates in an array that dates only i want to highlight. already i have highlighted 10 days from today but i want to again highlight within that 10 days.
how can i do it? any one please help.

This is my code:

```
function available(date) {
ymd = date.getFullYear() + "/" + ("0"+(date.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + "/" + ("0"+date.getDate()).slice(-2);
day = new Date(ymd).getDay();

if ($.inArray(ymd, arr) < 0) {
    return [false, "disabled"];
}  else { 
    return [true,"enabled"]; 
}}
$('#iDate').datepicker({ beforeShowDay: available });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6SyfY/1178/

Answer (score 0):

You can filter multiple times within your `function available(date)"{}`see [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6SyfY/1182/) for working example